# Capture keypress/keyup/keydown on any element using Angular directive

Tags: angular, events, angular-directive, keyboard-events

I need to capture keypress/keydown/keyup on any element. I did use a directive to handle it. So I defined a `KeyPressedDirective` :

```js
    import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Directive({
      selector: '[appKeyPressed]'
    })
    export class KeyPressedDirective {
    
      constructor(elRef:ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
        elRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('keypress',e=>console.log(e));
       }
    
    }
```

but by using the directive nothing happen and event did not capture.

```html
    <p appKeyPressed>Capture keypoard events</p>
```

How should I capture keyboard events?

Here is a StackBlits link:
[KeyPressDirective](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rtnuut)

Comment: `keypress/keydown/keyup`, These events will work on input element. Please try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use events keypress/keydown/keyup on any element, the element should have the attribute `tabindex`. So changing the directive to this will solve the problem:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appKeyPressed]'
})
export class KeyPressedDirective {

  constructor(elRef:ElementRef<HTMLElement>) {
    elRef.nativeElement.setAttribute('tabindex',0); // It can be checked that element has `tabindex` already
    elRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('keypress',e=>console.log(e));
   }
}
```

Here is StackBlitz link: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3pr5lq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fkey-pressed.directive.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

U can use `@HostListener(EVENT_NAME, [arguments you want to pass])` & BTW `keypress` means you are expecting Keyboard key press into an input, as I can see you are using a `p` paragraph I changed the code to use `mouseover` to demo `@HostListener`

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appKeyPressed]'
})
export class KeyPressedDirective {

   constructor() {}

   @HostListener('mouseover', ['$event'])
   customMouseOver($event) {
     console.log($event);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand when you can capture the keyEvents. Key events can be keyUp or KeyDown only triggered in the input or text field when user uses the keyboard.

So, this directive can be useful on `input` or `textarea`.

```
<input appKeyPressed/>

<textarea appKeyPressed> </textarea>
```

> How should I capture keyboard events?

Applying `appKeyPressed` on `p` tag won't give any results as there is no keyboard happening on it instead you can use mouse events like mouse-move-in or mouse-move-out. For that you can add `HostListener` too, but you can inbuilt methods:

```
<div (mouseover)="doSomething(whencursoroverParagraph)" (mouseout)="doSomething(whencursoisoutFromParagraph)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<input appKeyPressed/>`

This will work with `keypress` event, Please try